# Sound go back with Swift

Tags: swift, audio

I can play a sound when I click a button. I could find this and it works well with play:

```
var sound1 = AVAudioPlayer()
func setupAudioPlayerWithFile(file:NSString, type:NSString) -> AVAudioPlayer  {
    var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file as String, ofType: type as String)
    var url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    var error: NSError?
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
    return audioPlayer!
}
@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
    soun1.play()
}
```

in viewDidLoad:

```
sound1 = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("NameAudioFile", type:"mp3")
```

How can I go back 30 seconds from current time?

```
@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please improve your question. What kind of object is "soun1"?

Comment: Show `setupAudioPlayerWithFile` please

Comment: This code is stupid: `var sound1 = AVAudioPlayer(); sound1 = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("NameAudioFile", type:"mp3")` In the first line you create an AVAudioPlayer. In the second line you throw it away and replace it with a _different_ AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: @matt. Sorry I should have explained that sound1 = self.setupAudioPlayerWithFile("NameAudioFile", type:"mp3") is in viewDidLoad. Is now correct? if not, please explain how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Swift ternary conditional operator '?' You check if currentTime > 30 ? If true subtract 30 : otherwise equal 0

```
sound1.currentTime = sound1.currentTime > 30.0 ? sound1.currentTime - 30.0 : 0
```

**Edit**

As pointed by the OP just simply subtract 30s from the currentTime because it treats negative values as zero:

```
sound1.currentTime = sound1.currentTime - 30.0
```

[Ternary conditional operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

> The ternary conditional operator is a special operator with three
>   parts, which takes the form question ? answer1 : answer2. It is a
>   shortcut for evaluating one of two expressions based on whether
>   question is true or false. If question is true, it evaluates answer1
>   and returns its value; otherwise, it evaluates answer2 and returns its
>   value.

Comment: Thank you very much. (There is a small typo  without importance you have soun1 and in my original code is sound1) Can you explain your code please, I am very new in swift.

Comment: Ok, now I understand conditional operator. I do not see what made you think I was asking about any condition. Sorry if I did not explain well. I think the answer is much simpler. When the user click the button: sound1.currentTime = sound1.currentTime - 30.0

Comment: @Nrc you are right. it does work but I did not try. I just wanted to make sure to do not assign a negative value to it.